# Difficulty in implementing properties for members of type interface/reference

Tags: c#, linq, oop

I am facing difficulty in implementing properties for members of type interface/reference type. I have the following code:

```
public interface IPort: IBaseModel
{
  string PortName {get;set;}
}
public class Port : IPort
{
 public string PortName {get;set;}
}
public abstract class AbstractBaseModel : IBaseModel
{ 
 List<IBaseModel> children = new List<IBaseModel>();

 public void RegisterProperties(IBaseModel model)
 {
   // code to get the property info using reflection and update the children list.
   //   children.Add(propertyinfo.getValue(this,null))
 }
}

public Vessel : AbstractBaseModel
{
 public IPort Port {get ; set;}

  public Vessel()
 {
    base.RegisterProperties(this);
  }
}
```

In the Vessel class writing the property PortName in different forms exhibit different behaviour in the rest of the code. Need to know what are the differences in the various implementations and which one is the best when I need to invoke the properties in the abstract base class using reflection:

```
1. private IPort port;
   public IPort Port
   {
     get
     {
      if (port == null)
       port = new Port();
      return port;
      }
     set {port = value;}
   }

2. public IPort Port {get ; set;}

3. public IPort Port {
     get
      {
       if (port == null)
         port = new Port();
       return port;
       }
     set {}
   }
```

Also, I am using Entity framework to load my Vessel class. To my surprise the set accessors gets invoked every time I select an object of type Vessel in the LINQ code (with 'value' as null of the property). Any pointers for this would be helpful.

Comment: Can you add the code of IBaseModel

Comment: Maybe the first question should be: why do you need the property info's?

Comment: I don't get it! What you want to achieve accessing the properties via reflection on base class?

Comment: Curious why you're not using `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the entities to get notifications of properties changing.  This is the preferred way of doing this.  You're just duplicating work here.